# My function using recursion to return the number of occurrences of target in a nested list doesn't work

Tags: python, recursion, counting

```
def count(x, nxs, counter=0):

    for e in nxs:
        if type(e) == type([]):
            count(x, e)
        else:
            if e == x:
                counter += 1

    return counter
```

> print(count(2, [2, 9, [2, 1, 13, 2], 8, [2, 6]]))

This prints 1 instead of 4.

Comment: Why are you checking the `type` of `e`, rather than its value? What actually happens when you do the check for `[]`?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips how to debug your code.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe If `e` is a list, then the algorithm needs to make a recursive call.

Comment: Whatever `count(x, e)` does, you neither use nor return its value.

Comment: ```count(x, e)``` needs to be ```counter += count(x, e)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the return of the recursive call:

```
def count(x, nxs, counter=0):
    for e in nxs:
        if type(e) == type([]):
            counter += count(x, e)
        else:
            if e == x:
                counter += 1

    return counter
```

Since `counter` is used locally, you should just remove it from the parameter list:

```
def count(x, nxs):
    counter = 0
    for e in nxs:
        if type(e) == type([]):
            counter += count(x, e)
        else:
            if e == x:
                counter += 1

    return counter
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to explicitly pass the counter variable into the recursed function

```py
def count(x, nxs, counter=0):

    for e in nxs:
        if type(e) == type([]):
            counter = count(x, e, counter)
        else:
            if e == x:
                counter += 1

return counter
```